# Html 301 redirect in google appengine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, redirect

I am hosting a websiete on google appengine with python. I have seperate pages, in directories, and I need to know how to redirect from eg.:"www.example.com/page". whtn I dont add another "/" after page, it comes up with "404 not found". How do I change my redirect script to add this? here's my app.yaml:

```
    application: example-app
    version: 4
    runtime: python 
    api_version: 1

    handlers:
    - url: (.*)/
      static_files: static\1/index.html
      upload: static/index.html

    - url: /
      static_dir: static



    - url: /apps/(.*\.apk)
      mime_type: application/vnd.android.package-archive
      static_files: static/apps/\1
      upload: static/apps/(.*\.apk)

    - url: (.*)/apps
      script: directory.py

    - url: /comingsoon
      script: DirecotryHandler.py

    - url: /directory
      script: DirecotryHandler.py
```

and here's my directoryhandler.py:

```
    import os
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

    class DirecotryHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, tail):
    if tail == î:
    self.redirect(ë/directory/í, permanent=True)
    #TODO: respond to ì/directory/î request

    def head(self, tail):
    if tail == î:
    self.redirect(ë/directory/í, permanent=True)
    #TODO: respond to ì/directory/î request

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
    [
    (r'^/directory(/?)$', DirectoryPage),
    ])

    def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

    if __name__ == ì__main__î:
    main()
```

How do I edit my DirectryHandler.py to handle 301 redirects? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's your browser that handles the 301 redirects.  Your code is simply missing the Route `(r'^/comingsoon$', DirecotryHandler),` to generate the 301 redirect.

Then, when your browser calls `www.example.com/comingsoon`, your DirecotryHandler class handles the request and calls `self.redirect("/directory/", permanent=True)`.  That generates the 301 redirect as a response to your browser, which sees the new URL `/directory/` and requests it, which calls your `DirectoryPage` class.